# Variable have a type outside scope

Tags: c#, scope, var

I stumbled into some strange behavior that I dont understand and cant find an answer to. With `SubClass1` and `SubClass2` being subclasses to `BaseClass` I have the method:

```
private void SomeMethod(BaseClass obj)
{
    if (obj.GetType() == typeof(SubClass1))
    {
       var variable = (SubClass1) obj;
    }

    else if (obj.GetType() == typeof(SubClass2))
    {
        var variable  = (SubClass2) obj;
    }
}
```

To me it seems that the two declarations of `variable` are in different scopes and that `var` would be of either `SubClass1` or `SubClass2` according to the actual type of `obj` sent to the method.

But when I call this method with an object of type `SubClass2` the cast from `BaseClass` to `SubClass2` in the else-clause always returns null.

When I debug the code I see that immediately when entering the method, ie before I reached any of the `variable` declarations, `variable` is of type `SubClass1` which ofcource is the reason the cast of `obj` returns null.

Can anyone tell me why `variable` have a type before it is declared?

Comment: `But when I call this method with an object of type SubClass2 the cast from BaseClass to SubClass2 in the else-clause always returns null.` That's impossible.  It can *never* be `null` in that situation.

Comment: @Igor The code can never fail to cast, given that the type is checked first.

Comment: It's a debugger behavior, not your code. These are two separate variables, in separate scopes, of different type. Your code would not have compiled otherwise. Something else is going on.

Comment: To clarify what @Servy is saying, it cannot be null due to type mismatch. If it is a type mismatch, your code with throw an exception with an invalid type cast. If it is null, it is because the object (of type SubClass2) was null.

Comment: Instead of the type comparison, I would recommend `typeof(SubClass2).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()))`

Comment: @Theo There couldn't be a type mismatch, given that the type is checked before the cast.  And `obj` can't be `null` (at that point) because `GetType` was called on it, so it would throw before it gets to the cast if it was `null`.

Comment: @Theo You should just use `is` since the type is known at compile time.

Comment: @Servy true, but I have had issues (I forget what exactly) with `is` when the inheritance stack becomes complex and I found that to be the most reliable.

Comment: @Theo Your code is literally just a more complex and slower version of `is`.  The only difference is that your code throws an exception if `obj` is `null` instead of returning `false`, as it should.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Its not debugger behavior, my unittests fails with the code above, when I change the name of the second declaration they passes

Answer (score 3):

> To me it seems that the two declarations of `variable` are in different scopes and that `var` would be of either `SubClass1` or `SubClass2` according to the actual type of `obj` sent to the method.

That's not true.  You have two variables, one of type `SubClass1` and one of type `SubClass2`, they just both happen to have the same name.  The variables' types are determined at compile time, not runtime.  Your code is *identical* to having written:

```
private void SomeMethod(BaseClass obj)
{
    if (obj.GetType() == typeof(SubClass1))
    {
       SubClass1 variable = (SubClass1) obj;
    }

    else if (obj.GetType() == typeof(SubClass2))
    {
        SubClass2 variable  = (SubClass2) obj;
    }
}
```

Your code is simply a syntactic sugar for this code; preventing you from needing to type out the variables' types and letting the compiler figure it out for you.

> But when I call this method with an object of type `SubClass2` the cast from `BaseClass` to `SubClass2` in the else-clause always returns null.

This is impossible in the code shown.  A cast like this could only resolve to `null` if the value being cast is `null`, and `obj` can't be `null` at that point in your code or else `GetType` would have thrown a Null Reference Exception.

> When I debug the code I see that immediately when entering the method, ie before I reached any of the `variable` declarations, `variable` is of type `SubClass1` [...]

The first variable named `variable` is of type `SubClass1`, sure.  The second one is of type `SubClass2`.  That's what you defined the type of those variables as at compile time.

> which of cource is the reason the cast of `obj` returns null.

As mentioned earlier, it's *not* resulting in `null`.  It can't.  If the variable wasn't of the right type *the code wouldn't compile*; it wouldn't change the value at runtime.

> Can anyone tell me why `variable` have a type before it is declared?

The type of every variable is determined when you compile it, on the line that you declare it.

Comment: I would be ready to agree in all of your statements, its exactly how I picture things are working. But now Im actually experiance a different behavior and the answer "It cant" doesnt help me anything

Comment: @user613068 Either you aren't actually seeing what you claim to be seeing, or your code is different than the code you've shown.